# How to read the last but one line from a file?

Tags: c, windows

I'm creating an application, which has to get some data from text files. The problem is, that the data i need is in the last but one line in the text file. Is there a way to read the last but one line somehow? I only need the last but one lines content. Could someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: If it's a big file, then your two current answers are pretty hopeless. Seek to the end, then read backwards (into a a suitably sized buffer) until you've located enough line ends to identify the line you need.

Comment: @David: Or use `MapViewOfFile` and let the OS worry about suitable buffering.  Deal with empty lines at the end as necessary, call `strrchr` twice, and grab the data in between.

Comment: @Ben Well, once we've got beyond reading the entire file, your suggestions are like micro-optimisations!!  ;-)

Comment: @David: Maybe, but "read backwards" is not the easiest concept using conventional I/O functions.  "Call `strrchr` to search backwards" is quite straightforward, however.

Comment: @Ben How do you decide where in the file to start searching from with strrchr? Trial and error. Even so probably a neat way to do it because I guess there has to be some trial and error.

Comment: @David: Address returned from `MapViewOfFile` + offset returned by `GetFileSizeEx`?  Ok, `strrchr` wouldn't be all that helpful, since it looks for a terminating NUL instead of taking a length.  And there's no reverse version of `memchr`.  Just scanning backward with a pointer would be best.

Comment: There are some 'files' (I should stay streams) that are not seekable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the whole file, keeping two lines, then discard the last one, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int secondtolast(char *dst, size_t maxlen, FILE *h) {
  char *line[2];
  int i = 0;

  line[0] = malloc(maxlen);
  if (!line[0]) return 1;
  *line[0] = 0;
  line[1] = malloc(maxlen);
  if (!line[1]) {
      free(line[0]); /* return memory to the OS */
      return 1;
  }
  *line[1] = 0;

  while (fgets(line[i], maxlen, h)) i = !i;
  strcpy(dst, line[i]);

  free(line[0]);
  free(line[1]);

  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  char l2[8192];
  if (secondtolast(l2, sizeof l2, stdin)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "no memory");
  }
  printf("second to last line: %s", l2);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty code. It reads all lines to get the number of all lines, rewinds the file to the beginning and again reads lines until the last but two. Finally the last but one line is read and stored in the variable `lastLineButOne`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUF 255

int getNoOfLines(FILE *f) {
    int ctr=0;
    char temp[BUF];
    while(fgets(temp,BUF,f) != NULL)
        ctr++;
    return ctr;
}

int main() {
    int i;
    FILE *f=fopen("apps.txt","r");
    char lastLineButOne[BUF];
    char temp[BUF];
    int noOfLines=getNoOfLines(f);
    rewind(f);
    for(i = 0; i < noOfLines-2; i++) {
        fgets(temp,BUF,f);
    }
    fgets(lastLineButOne,BUF,f);
    printf("%s",lastLineButOne);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```